# How to profile nodejs in production which is containerize

Tags: node.js, amazon-ecs

I am running a nodejs app in AWS ECS. I would like to profile my nodejs app on production environment
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/
I have gone through the above url but not use how to run for a containerized production environment.